# What happens if an edit privileged used edits a post before another user's edit gets approved or rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Let's say a user edited a post but it was not visible (as user didn't have edit privileges so edit needs to be approved or rejected by an [edit privileged user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)).

Now before this edit gets approved, an another edit privileged user edits the post.

Now, how will this be handled? Will the edit of previous user be rejected automatically or it will be handled in some other way?

Answer (score 4):

Since once suggested-edit posted and system will show edit(1) button which opens the review, there is very less chance of happening this case. It happens when edit privileged user starts editing the same time to a user suggesting an edit. In that case, suggested edit will be rejected by Community ♦ user with the reason **"This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"** but it doesn't count for automatic ban from suggesting-edit.

Visit [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/260388) or [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/260388) for detailed information:

> #### A user with full edit privileges saves an edit over yours
>
> If a user with full editing privileges for a post (including the original poster) begins editing the post at the same time as you, and they save their edit after you have already suggested it, then your suggested edit will be overridden in favor of their fully-privileged edit.
>
> This is known in software as an *optimistic lock*. This is an edge case, and does not happen often because users with full privileges who try to edit a post after you submit your edit will be directed to your suggested edit instead. Thus, when one person starts editing a post, we do not need to lock everyone else out. While the UI attempts to avoid these situations (by prompting you with "an edit has been made to this post; click to load"), they do sometimes occur.
>
> This sometimes appears strange to a viewer—as if Community ♦ has immediately rejected their edit, without warning, with no hesitation.
>
> [image: Conflicted with a subsequent edit]
>
> Do not be alarmed! This is just concurrent modification working its evil magic once again. This type of rejection will not be counted towards automated edit bans. Simply submit your edit again and it may actually be reviewed.
>
> Another way this can occur is if a fully-privileged user makes an edit, then you suggest another edit right afterwards, and then the first user makes another edit during their [5-minute grace period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info). In that case, a new revision is not created, but your suggestion is still automatically rejected due to the edit conflict.

Answer (score 4):

There are two cases here.

1. If there is a pending suggested edit on a post, another user cannot edit the post until it's rejected or approved.

   [image: Suggested Edit pending]
2. If there are two different users editing at the same time, there will be an edit conflict and the suggested edit will be rejected by Community user.

   [image: Community rejecting an edit]

   In this case, the advantage goes to the user with edit privileges. Their edit will be shown and the suggested edit will be automatically rejected with the reason "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit".

I'm not sure which one you are talking about. The answer is [Reject](https://media.giphy.com/media/l2SpUoAPo0CBOkyxq/giphy.gif) if it's the second case. However, this [doesn't effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137611/357396) the suggested edit ban because it's not the fault of user who suggested the edit.

Comment: Case2 is valid even if both the users hv edit privilege...i remember u edited one of my answers https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22525/12304 and i was also editing at the sametime..and ur edit got rejected automatically, i came to know this from ur comment that u also edited it :)

Comment: @YDS My edit was not rejected. It was edited. It was just overruled after you edited. If both the users have edit privileges, it doesn't go to review queue, the post is directly edited.

Comment: But i was unaware of ur edit...in other sense i didn't edit afyer ur edit.. so conflict must hv occurred...and it seems in conflict ur edit was rejected by system...not sure if it was due to the fact that another edit was from post owner or it always give preference to last edit..

Comment: @YDS There is no question of rejecting my edit because I'm not a <1k user when that edit occurred. There was a conflict because we were editing at the same time. Approval or edit is only case for <1kers. Not for others. You were writing answer when my edit was placed. Look at revision 5, my edit is placed and not rejected.

Comment: I meant overruled automatically by system..i didn't edit ur version, it automatically merged/overruled...